Invoke-Webrequest Post
I want to use Invoke-webRequest Post object to search on google without a search query instead I want to use InputFields
Input
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.google.com' $response 
Output
InputFields       : {@{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<INPUT type=hidden value=en-NG 
                    name=hl>; outerText=; tagName=INPUT; type=hidden; value=en-NG; 
                    name=hl}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<INPUT type=hidden 
                    value=hp name=source>; outerText=; tagName=INPUT; type=hidden; 
                    value=hp; name=source}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<INPUT 
                    type=hidden name=biw>; outerText=; tagName=INPUT; type=hidden; 
                    name=biw}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<INPUT type=hidden 
                    name=bih>; outerText=; tagName=INPUT; type=hidden; name=bih}...}

I have only tried the search query but I have no idea how to use the Input Fields to search a website like www.google.com
